# After Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade NTFS is read only problem?

Tags: ntfs, do-release-upgrade, nvme, 22.04

I have a NTFS partition. Before upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, it was working perfectly and I could read/write/delete files with no problem.

However, after upgrading I can only read the disk and it says that it is a **fuse** filesystem, as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image: Ntfs Properties]

How do I fix it so it can be read/write/delete again?

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows? If so disable its Fast Startup feature and shutdown. If not then you shouldn't keep NTFS partitions around because when errors happen there's no way to correct them from Ubuntu or any other Linux. NTFS requires Windows tools.

Comment: This is not a Microsoft Windows problem.

I have two laptops, both upgraded to the latest Ubuntu 22.04, I have the same problem on both laptops, I can only read from the disks.

I do dualboot - In each laptop, there are two nvmee drives. One drive for Ubuntu and another drive for windows. I use GRUB as the bootloader, so windows has absolute no control over the Ubuntu boot. I do also boot into windows from GRUB.

Comment: It seems you understood very little, if any, of my previous comment. Your reply reads as and entirely different movie. Again, if you're dual-booting then please boot Windows, make sure Windows' Fast Startup feature is disabled and check the drives for errors. Then shutdown instead of rebooting to Ubuntu. Report back.

Comment: Disabling fast boot in windows did the trick. Thanks enormously! Your wisdom is deeply appreciated!  My Apologies.. I was so focused on that it was a Ubuntu setting is was missing

Comment: @ChanganAuto you should turn this into an answer and get some points!

Comment: I too am having this trouble and my windows pc doesnt have fast boot enabled. i had disabled it years ago and double checked that it is still disabled and yup it is

Comment: i cant even install ntfsfix as the packae doesnt exist....

Answer (score 9):

For my case, The command `sudo dmesg | tail` shows:

```
ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
```

It seems the new `ntfs3` driver does not support the 'windows_names' flag anymore.
Base on [this suggestion](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/pull/917#issuecomment-962596147) I made `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` file containing:

```
[defaults]
ntfs_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID
ntfs_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,nls,umask,dmask,fmask,nohidden,sys_immutable,discard,force,sparse,showmeta,prealloc,no_acs_rules,acl,noatime
```

Comment: ¡Excelent! This was the solution for me. I have Fast Boot enabled and working like a charm.

Comment: It did the trick for me too !

Comment: Despite not changing anything in `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` @hpascual answer worked and re-installing the ntfs driver solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt remove ntfsprogs && sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Then reboot your system.

Comment: I have the same error, but ntfs-3g is already installed, and not ntfsprogs.

Comment: Despite having three downvotes, just a side-note that another new-user posted in an "answer" (that will likely be deleted since it is "not an answer") that *this* answer was the solution that worked for them.  Unfortunately, they don't have the rep to comment or upvote just yet, but I encouraged them to return to it when they do to upvote it.

Comment: Despite not changing anything in `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` just re-installing the ntfs driver solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -6):

Format your disk with NTFS format.

```
sudo mkfs -t ntfs /dev/sdc1
```

If you see error like " `mkfs: failed to execute mkfs.ntfs: No such file or directory` " then, install ntfs-3g package > `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

After that, Format with NTFS, and, you'll access ntfs with no issue.

Comment: No issue? The data, if any, will be gone.