# Kubuntu 22.04 stopped to mount Intel RAID0 device

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, raid, ntfs

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and Kubuntu LTS for years. I have Intel RAID0 created in BIOS long time ago. I can confirm both Kubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 could work with it. It has NTFS filesystem.

However *after upgrading to Kubuntu 22.04* I can't mount it. Not manually, not automatically.

This is my previously-working `/etc/fstab` related line:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6626CA6826CA38B7 /mnt/6626CA6826CA38B7 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Now there is no `6626CA6826CA38B7` device inside `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` directory at all.

I **do** have `ntfs-3g` installed.

### What I tried

##### dmesg errors

I looked into `dmesg` and saw one error message: `ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'`. Tried solution [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404069/after-ubuntu-22-04-upgrade-ntfs-is-read-only-problem), but it did not help.

##### Checking Disk

I booted into Windows and started chkdsk. It found some bad blocks and fixed them automatically. But nothing changed in Kubuntu.

##### Inspecting devices

```
sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 мая 23 14:07 661A0E761A0E4411 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 мая 23 14:04 AFC0-0C3D -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 мая 23 14:04 B268F1E468F1A76F -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 мая 23 14:12 C2241F87241F7E1B -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 мая 23 14:04 dc6d0abb-3ea5-491a-84eb-c1a455509600 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 мая 23 14:04 E8F2-6F0E -> ../../sda2
```

```
sudo lsblk

sda                        8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk   
├─sda1                     8:1    0   450M  0 part   
├─sda2                     8:2    0   100M  0 part   /boot/efi
├─sda3                     8:3    0    16M  0 part   
├─sda4                     8:4    0 110,7G  0 part   /media/alex/661A0E761A0E4411
└─sda5                     8:5    0   524M  0 part   
sdb                        8:16   0 238,5G  0 disk   
├─sdb1                     8:17   0   512M  0 part   
└─sdb2                     8:18   0   238G  0 part   /
sdc                        8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk   
└─isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage 253:0    0 931,5G  0 dmraid 
sdd                        8:48   0 931,5G  0 disk   
└─isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage 253:0    0 931,5G  0 dmraid
```

```
sudo blkid

/dev/sdb2: UUID="dc6d0abb-3ea5-491a-84eb-c1a455509600" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f229cbda-d744-4557-9f06-78952cd5f2b4"
/dev/sdd: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="AFC0-0C3D" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="79226711-2f9a-4eec-b43a-0d0abe8ae512"
/dev/sdc: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sda4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="661A0E761A0E4411" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="2fa7fbec-f59f-46c3-b819-0330861f1350"
/dev/sda2: LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="E8F2-6F0E" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="90537d26-429e-43b1-a060-cced204ab634"
/dev/sda5: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="C2241F87241F7E1B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="916cac95-59d2-42cd-8a85-2914ff9bf96c"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="M-PM-^RM-PM->M-QM-^AM-QM-^AM-QM-^BM-PM-0M-PM-=M-PM->M-PM-2M-PM-8M-QM-^BM-QM-^L" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="B268F1E468F1A76F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="366530b9-cadd-48bc-9056-4611ca88a8e7"
/dev/mapper/isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage: PTUUID="96da5e29-66e8-418a-8e78-6b9ab59d74a4" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="3a4af120-dfa1-4796-8cb0-0249233f897a"
```

As far as I understand, OS can see each device separately (`sdc` and `sdd`), but ca't see "merged" disk/partition.

Not sure what is `/dev/mapper/isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage`.

##### manually mounting

Well there is not really much I can try since OS can't see device. I tried to mount this device: `sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage /media/alex/temp`, but got error:

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

##### P.S

Windows Fast Boot feature is disabled. Some articles says it is related, but not in my case. Also can confirm disk working great in Windows: I can read and write to it. Speed is good, no errors noticed.

Oh, also `Disks` utility can see "1,0 TB Block device" (/dev/dm-0), but says it `Contents 1,0 TB Unallocated Space`

##### What is next?

I am running out of ideas. I prefer not to format/reset disks, but could try later after dumping all data somewhere else.

##### Update

Checked dmraid, but is says set already active.

```
sudo dmraid -ay
RAID set "isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage" already active
```

Answer (score 0):

### Part of a solution

```
sudo partprobe /dev/mapper/isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage
```

As manual says, `partprobe - inform the OS of partition table changes`. I gave it a try and it worked! Device appeared everywhere: in Dolphin, in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` directory etc.

After that, usual `mount -a` worked without an issue.

**But I have to do it after every reboot.** At this moment I am looking into "how should it be". Any comment will be appreciated.

At this moment I am using workaround: I just added above command to crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/partprobe /dev/mapper/isw_ecfidjbdhb_Storage
```